# How can I use llen command result to insert rpush's data?

Tags: node.js, transactions, redis

I just want to use `'llen "someKey"' return values(list count)  to add 'rpush' value` in one transactions.

```
var count = llen "keys"
rpush "keys" count
```

how can I use this one transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Lua to execute both commands in a single transaction. The command would be something like this :

```
eval "local len=redis.call('llen' , 'someKey'); redis.call('rpush', 'keys', len);" 2 someKey keys
```

Note that the last parameters are the number of keys involved in the process and the list of them. This is usefull if you have many redis instances.